# Cannot understand how does he find the minimum value of this funtion

Tags: calculus

My teacher has find the minimum value of $y = x + \frac{2}{x}$ when $x \ge 0$ without using 
differential:

$y = x + \frac{2}{x}$

Multiplied both side by $x$ and moved $y$ to other side

$x^2 - yx + 2 = 0$

Then he wrote that having an answer in this equation is conditioned by

$y^2 - 8 \ge 0$  (He used $b^2 - 4ac$ formula)

$y \ge 2\sqrt{2}$

The answer is $2\sqrt{2}$ and it's correct.

Can anyone explain this solution?

Comment: Here the assumption is $x>0$ and we can use AM, GM Inequality as well : $$x+\frac2x\ge 2\sqrt{x\cdot\frac2x}$$

Comment: yes sorry i forgot to note that, X > 0

Comment: @omidh, Where is your confusion?

Comment: @Chinny84 y doesn't decrease when we move away from zero...

Comment: @omidh I noticed another problem with what I said .. Cheers

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I just want to know how this guy can find minimum value of a function without actually using differentials So I can use it to, I can see the steps but can not understand it

Comment: Towards the end, you mean $y\ge 2\sqrt{2}$.  For a very nice book, please see Niven's Maxima and Minima without Calculus.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yea sorry, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the discriminant is smaller than zero($b^2-4ac<0$) than $x_{1,2}\in\mathbb{C}$ so clearly $b^2-4ac\geq0$ now if $y\in(-2\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{2})$ it means that there is no solution in reals,and since $x>0$ than $y>0$ so we have that $y\geq2\sqrt{2}$ clearly since we are looking for the minimum we pick the smallest $y$ which is $y=2\sqrt{2}$ And since we have a positive $x$ that satisfies that equation we are done.

Answer (score 1):

In general if $y=f(x)>0$, and if $f$ has minimun or maximun in $(x_0.y_0)$, and $$F(x)=f(x)-y_0=y-y_0=y-f(x_0)$$ Then $F$ has minimun or maximun when $F(x)=0$